# SWT toolbar questions

Tags: java, swt

I've 2 questions regardind SWT:

1. is there a quick way to align toolbar to the right side of a window (at startup) ?
2. can I create a toolbar that occupies 100% with of the window ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, CoolBar does not have an alignment field. However it does have bounds, which can be used to align it to the right side and make it occupy the entire width of the window. CoolBar does not allow height to be over 21, so the height of the window dimensions must be taken into account to make it fill the window. To do this, compute the necessary client area size and then resize the shell accordingly. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004134/setting-size-of-inner-region-of-java-swt-shell-window) might help with the resizing.

```
//This code will make the coolBar take up the entire window width running Windows 7 with default windows
Rectangle shellBounds = shell.getClientArea();
coolBar.setBounds(0, 0, shellBounds.width, shellBounds.height);
```

You can use this same logic to justify the coolBar to the right side of the screen.

```
//Justify the toolbar to the right side of the screen
int coolBarWidth = 200; //arbitrarily chosen dimensions
int coolBarHeight = 40;
coolBar.setBounds(shellBounds.width - coolBarWidth, 0, coolBarWidth, coolBarHeight);
```

Furthermore, some coolBar elements have alignment parameters in their constructors.

```
CLabel lblTest = new CLabel(coolBar, SWT.LEFT); //SWT.LEFT could be replaced with SWT.CENTER or SWT.RIGHT
```

I hope this helped.