# Setting size of inner region of Java SWT shell window

Tags: java, swt

In a Java SWT shell window, how do I set its inner size than its whole window frame size?

For instance, if I use shell.setSize(300, 250) this would make the whole window appearing as exactly 300x250. This 300x250 includes the size of the window frame.

How can I set the inner size, that is the content display region of the shell window to 300x250 instead? That's this 300x250 excludes the width of the window frame.

I tried to minus some offset values but the thing is different Operating Systems have different window frame sizes. So having a constant offset would not be accurate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your question what I understood is that you want to set the dimension of the `Client Area`. And in SWT lingo it is defined as *`a rectangle which describes the area of the receiver which is capable of displaying data (that is, not covered by the "trimmings").`*

You cannot directly set the dimension of `Client Area` because there is no API for it. Although you can achieve this by a little hack. In the below sample code I want my client area to be **`300 by 250`**.  To achieve this I have used the `shell.addShellListener()` event listener. When the shell is completely active (see the *`public void shellActivated(ShellEvent e)`*) then I calculate the different margins and again set the size of my shell. The calculation and resetting of the shell size gives me the desired shell size.

**`>>Code:`**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MenuTest {

    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Display display = new Display ();
        final Shell shell = new Shell (display);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        layout.numColumns = 1;
        shell.setLayout(layout);
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,true));
        final Menu bar = new Menu (shell, SWT.BAR);
        shell.setMenuBar (bar);

        shell.addShellListener(new ShellListener() {

            public void shellIconified(ShellEvent e) {
            }
            public void shellDeiconified(ShellEvent e) {
            }
            public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent e) {
            }
            public void shellClosed(ShellEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Client Area: " + shell.getClientArea());
            }
            public void shellActivated(ShellEvent e) {
                int frameX = shell.getSize().x - shell.getClientArea().width;
                int frameY = shell.getSize().y - shell.getClientArea().height;
                shell.setSize(300 + frameX, 250 + frameY);
            }
        });     

        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your example has been very very helpful! Thank you!!

Comment: There is no hack needed. `computeTrim` returns the bounds that are necessary to display a given client area.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you should set the size of the inner component to the needed size and use the method `pack()` (of the frame).

Comment: I have a menu control at the top of the frame. The pack() doesn't consider the extra height of the menu bar but just the content of in the frame. How do I get the height of the menu bar or let pack() consider the size of the menubar as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class SWTClientAreaTest
{
    Display display;
    Shell shell;
    final int DESIRED_CLIENT_AREA_WIDTH = 300;
    final int DESIRED_CLIENT_AREA_HEIGHT = 200;

    void render()
    {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.CENTER);

        Point shell_size = shell.getSize();
        Rectangle client_area = shell.getClientArea();

        shell.setSize
        (
            DESIRED_CLIENT_AREA_WIDTH + shell_size.x - client_area.width,
            DESIRED_CLIENT_AREA_HEIGHT + shell_size.y - client_area.height
        );

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SWTClientAreaTest appl = new SWTClientAreaTest();
        appl.render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments that describe the answer and address the specific questions asked. Pure code answers are frowned on at StackOverflow

Answer (score -1):

Use `computeTrim` to calculate the bounds that are necessary to display a given client area. The method returns a rectangle that describes the bounds that are needed to provide room for the client area specified in the arguments.

In this example the size of the shell is set so that it is capable to display a client area of 100 x 200 (width x height):

```java
Rectangle bounds = shell.computeTrim(0, 0, 100, 200);
shell.setSize(bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

This article describes the terms used by SWT for widget dimensions:
https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm