# Can I programatically specify size of Eclipse RCP Editor Part?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have some users that wish to set the size of an EditorPart in an Eclipse RCP app to a specific dimension (in pixels).

This is so that a screenshot of the editor contents *exactly* matches the PowerPoint slide they want to paste it into, which will guarantee zero pixelation.

I know it's possible to manually change the size of an Eclipse EditorPart, but can't find a programmatic way.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Why can't you manually size the editor part to the desired size, take a screenshot and then paste the screenshot into power point?

Comment: There are no official APIs to set the editor size. You can use `setBounds` on controls in the editor (instead of Layouts) to set their size.

Comment: @DuncanKrebs - yes, that's possible. But, there isn't a screen element that tells them the current size of the Editor Part - so it's either guess work, or to install another S/W tool to do it.

That's cumbersome when they know the projector they're using is, for example, exactly 1920x1080px.

Answer (score 0):

While it won't solve my specific scenario, I have found an alternate strategy.

If an EditorPart is dragged out of the main Eclipse Window, so it's floating, then it is possible to set the size of the Shell that contains this floating pane.

The size of the shell just needs to be adjusted to allow for the decorations/trimming around the editor within it.

More details here: [Setting size of inner region of Java SWT shell window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004134/setting-size-of-inner-region-of-java-swt-shell-window)